# Neutron/DVR promiscuous mode for all instances by default

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have some troubles with OpenStack setup with Neutron/DVR networking. All interfaces promiscuous mode by default, and if some virtual machines in one network run in one hypervisor I see on all virtual machines all network traffic. In this scenario new virtual machine with no applications have 1 Gbit/s incoming traffic directed for another virtual machines in this hypervisor.

It's my mistake in configuration or it's by design? I want to disable promiscuous mode for virtual machines.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question right, but an instance is supposed to only see traffic of the Neutron network(s) to which it is connected. I would lean towards a configuration error, since I have never heard of anything like this. You don't provide any information about version, architecture, configuration etc. of your cloud; hard to help you. Also, I don't understand the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: I found the cause of my problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1732067 :(